# Constructing a function from level sets

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, differential-geometry

Suppose we know what the projection of the level sets into the xy-plane of some function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ looks like. How can I construct a closed form for $f$ by "lifting" the level sets to their desired heights?

Comment: How do you know the level sets? Implicitly? Parametrically?

Comment: Parametrically.

Comment: As in $\gamma_c(t)$ for the level curve $f(x,y)=c$ ?

Comment: So for example the level sets are concentric circles which we write as $(a \sin(b),a \cos(b))$

Comment: Then the surface is given parametrically  by $(t,z) \mapsto (x_z(t), y_z(t), z)$.

Comment: By the way, we ordinarily refer to the level sets (in this case curves) as subsets of $\Bbb R^2$ in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think (but I'm not sure) that the answer you're looking for comes from solving a differential equation.

Knowing the level curves means, in principle, that you know their slopes at each point $(x,y)$, or, equivalently, a nonzero tangent vector $(a(x,y),b(x,y))$ at each point. Therefore we must have $\nabla f$ orthogonal to that vector at each point. This means that
$$df = \lambda(x,y)\big({-}b(x,y)\,dx + a(x,y)\,dy\big)$$
for some nonzero function $\lambda$ (classically called the integrating factor for the differential equation). As long as $(a,b)\ne (0,0)$, such an integrating factor always exists. So you recover $f$ by integrating.

For example, with your circles, we have $(a(x,y),b(x,y)) = (-y,x)$ and the differential equation becomes
$$df = \lambda(x\,dx + y\, dy),$$
from which we conclude that $f(x,y) = F(\frac12(x^2+y^2))$ for any function $F$.